# How to solve Node and reactapp error when deploying to heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, package.json

I am trying to deploy my node and react web app. I have completed all the steps for the deployment. But when I run this command, `git push heroku main`. Everything goes fine up to here
[image]
, and all the dependencies get installed, and then error occurs,

```
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix frontend && npm 
run build --prefix frontend
remote:
remote: npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
remote: npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
remote: npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
remote: npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
remote: npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
remote: npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

And the thing is I don't even have `fsevents` in my `package.json` file. And also the error clearly says that fsevents needs linux in os but the thing is where to edit this
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to install fsevents before push? `npm install fsevents --save`

Comment: no I haven't done that

Answer (score 1):

first check the  and npm version

$ node -v   >>
v16.2.0

$ npm -v   >>
7.13.0

then check your server package.json inside engine update same version like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LruWH.png)

and also remove the fsevent if in case not use anymore

and commit and push once again
i hope it helpfull